# How to read strings using loop with function and methods in Java

Tags: java, string, function, loops, methods

I am a newbie in java and need some little bit of help.
So i should be able to display the string message to the user via the filestream stream.

here is my main method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    writeline("Hello World!", System.out);
}
```

and here is my writeline method

```
public static int writeline (String message, PrintStream stream)
{
    //need some loops to read in each character of "Hello World!" and display.
}
```

I know you can use String method charAt and length method.

any idea how to tackle this situation??

any tips will be much appreciated.

thanks

also, value of message  are expected to be NULL terminated character arrays

and values of stream are expected to be System.out and System.err.

Comment: To make it a lot simpler, couldn't you just use ```System.out.println("Hello World!");``` ?

Comment: Why do you need loop? You could simply use `stream.println(message);` Also why the return value is of `int` type?

Comment: This is probably homework guys

Comment: @Arvind I need to read each character string of hello world and able to print it out. I need to return the value of string for hello world.

Comment: ***return the value of string for hello world***, kindly explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unnecessary.
But since you asked, in the method writeline() you can try following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
{    
   stream.print(message.charAt(i));
}
```

But again, there is no need of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String s = "Hello World!";
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
   char c = s.charAt(i);
}
```